# Help with a unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php

Now I have fixed the problem the T_ELSE parse error is not displaying anymore, But then how can I direct the code to display the if or the else?

Well users are going to come from either page1.php or page2.php

```
url coming from page1.php
cart.php?ids=1

url coming from page2.php
cart.php?idc=1
```

for instance if the url is coming from page1.php then cart is going to receive it like

$ids= isset($_GET['ids'])?(int) $_GET['ids']:null;

$idc= isset($_GET['idc'])?(int) $_GET['idc']:null;

```
if ($ids) { 
display something
} 
elseif($idc) {
display something different
}
else 
{ 

display nothing has passed 
}
```

Those are the conditions I have right but it is not working properly since it will display the else message "display nothing has passed". Again it will display the else statement even if I come from page1.php or page2.php. I guess the conditions are not well set up or it is passing empty. How can I set up the conditions so it can display either $ids statement or the elseif $idc.

Comment: You **need** to correctly indent your code.

Comment: post the real code, nobody can help you with this...

Comment: look at line 378 - make sure you mark your comments

Comment: "} end of if statement" should be "} // end of if statement"

Comment: Are you working with an IDE? They will help show if you have any missing, `;`, `{`, `}`, etc.

Comment: @Rufinus: But human beings **do** care.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275349/suggestion-for-non-indenting-blocks

Comment: @Slaks: true, true. but his style misses any common codingconvention anyways. :)

Comment: hi see the new edited script above

Comment: hey thank you @Slaks for the article on how to indent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that 'blabla' isn't actually in your code but there is, in fact, something meaningful there.

Remember to test for something with your if statement.

```
if($some_condition) {
  for(blabla) {
    if($another_condition) {
    } // end of if statement inside the for loop
  }   // end of for loop.
}     // end of if statement 
else{ // line 379

}// end of else statement
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (true) {
    for (blabla) {
        if (false) {
            // do something
        }// end of if statement inside the for loop

    } //end of for loop.

} // end of if statement 
else { // line 379
    // do something else

}// end of else statement
```

Answer (score 0):

An `else` statement must immediately follow an `if` block, and will be associated with the `if` block that it follows.  There cannot even be an extra `}` between the `if` block and the `else`.

You will get that error if you have anything other than whitespace or commetns between the `}` that closes the `if` and the `else`.

Can you show us *exactly* what that part of the file contains?

Comment: right now it is working but then I have some logic issues, please take a look a the edited script above.

Answer (score 0):

end of if statement should be commented out like so.

```
    if {
  for (blabla) {
    if {

    }// end of if statement inside the for loop

  } //end of for loop.

} // end of if statement 
else{ // line 379


}// end of else statement
```